# Testing an observable interval in ngOnInit

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I've been trying to get this test running for over a day now, and I am out of options.

I have tried using variants of `fakeAsync`, and injecting a `testScheduler`, but the `tick()` function seems to have no effect, and, as I will describe, injecting a `testScheduler` works too well.

The function I wish to test is this:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  ...
  interval(environment.verificationCheckPollingInterval).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy)).subscribe(_ =>
    this.store.dispatch(fromAccount.checkEmailVerificationStatus()));
}
```

I do realise that polling for email verification isn't ideal practice, but that is a story for another day.

My jasmine testing function looks like this:

```js
describe('After the verification interval has elapsed', () => {
  it('should dispatch a check verification email action after the verification interval has elapsed', fakeAsync(() => {
    tick(environment. environment.verificationCheckPollingInterval);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    testScheduler.run(({ expectObservable, flush, cold }) => {
      expectObservable(store.scannedActions$.pipe(
        ofType(fromAccount.ActionTypes.checkEmailVerificationStatus),
        map((_) => true))).toBe('a', { a: true });
    });
  }));
});
```

The `tick` function seems to do nothing at all.

Another approach is to inject a `scheduler` into the component, and to change the subscription to

```js
interval(environment.verificationCheckPollingInterval, this.scheduler).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy)).subscribe(_ =>
    this.store.dispatch(fromAccount.checkEmailVerificationStatus()));
```

and then in my test setup, include

```js
{ provide: Scheduler, useValue: testScheduler }
```

But this works too well (besides the fact that I'll be modifying production code to support tests, which is far from ideal). The reason it works too well is that if I put a breakpoint on the subscription handler, it gets called repeatedly without any delays, and at each step, the `testScheduler.frame` value has advanced by `1000` frames (my polling interval is 1 second). This hangs my browser and makes my laptop heat up somewhat alarmingly.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to test `interval` without setting my laptop on fire?

**UPDATE**

I have had one very sensible suggestion, which unfortunately failed.

Given this code:

```js
describe('After the verification interval has elapsed', () => {
  it('should dispatch a check verification email action after the verification interval has elapsed', (done) => {
    store.scannedActions$.pipe(
      ofType(fromAccount.ActionTypes.checkEmailVerificationStatus),
      take(1)).subscribe(x => {
        console.log('action dispatched', x);
        done();
    });
  });
});
```

the `console.log` call gets invoked, but the test fails with the message

> Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within 5000ms (set by
>   jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)

Comment: What is the value of `environment.verificationCheckPollingInterval`? It seems that your store never fires the action or the one dispatched is not the type of `fromAccount.ActionTypes.checkEmailVerificationStatus`

Comment: 1000. It's definitely dispatching the action, because the `console.log` call is getting picked up. Time is a can of worms.

Comment: Why u even use interval in such a case?

Comment: Can you share code of `checkEmailVerificationStatus` function as well?

Comment: @mamosek -- because I'm using Firebase, and the web socket option is not available. Polling in this case is a pragmatic compromise.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner -- `checkEmailVerificationStatus` is just a string. I'm using the `ofType` pipe from the NgRx effects library.

Comment: @RobLyndon , yes but why are you using interval in this case. Why you want to check email status every time in interval? Is this kind of validation? If so, its not a good solution though

Answer (score 1):

You could simply subscribe to the `store` and call `done` when you are done with the tests.

For more info, you can read it [here](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async#callbacks)

```
describe('After the verification interval has elapsed', () => {
  it('should dispatch a check verification email action after the verification interval has elapsed', (done) => {
      store.scannedActions$.pipe(
        ofType(fromAccount.ActionTypes.checkEmailVerificationStatus))
        .subscribe(_ => {
            // run your tests here
            done();
        });
  });
});
```

Comment: Great suggestion -- unfortunately it fails. I'll add the description of the failure to the question.